# Azure DevOps SQL DB Deploy

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, release, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to deploy a dacpac with db references to 2 other dbs using Azure DevOps. I'm unable to find the right syntax for mentioning additional arguments for the sqlcmd variables for those dbs. I keep getting 'Unrecognized command line argument' error everytime I trigger deployment. the current syntax I'm using is

```
/Variables:variable1 = "value1" /Variables:variable2 = "value2"
```

Comment: edit: I was able to solve this by removing spaces around '='. but i'm now at the next roadblock 'Variable1' is not a valid argument for the 'Publish' action.

Comment: edit: I was using /p for the variables, changed to /v and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15 and use

SQLCMD Variables
The following table describes the format of the option that you can use to override the value of a SQL command (sqlcmd) variable used during a publish action. The values of variable specified on the command line override other values assigned to the variable (for example, in a publish profile).

Parameter   Default Description
/Variables:{PropertyName}={Value}       Specifies a name value pair for an action-specific variable; {VariableName}={Value}. The DACPAC file contains the list of valid SQLCMD variables. An error results if a value is not provided for every variable.

/Variables: /v  {PropertyName}={Value}  Specifies a name value pair for an action-specific variable; {VariableName}={Value}. The DACPAC file contains the list of valid SQLCMD variables. An error results if a value is not provided for every variable.